# How to validate JPA connection properties?

Tags: java, validation, jpa, parameters, connection

I am using JPA in a JavaSE application and wrote a class to manage database connections and persist objects to the database.
The connection parameters for the database connection are passed using the class constructor and the class has a method to validate the connection parameters.

```
public class DatabaseManager{

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

    public DatabaseManager(String connectionDriver, String connectionUrl, String username, String password) {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", connectionDriver);
        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", connectionUrl);
        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", username);
        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("name of persistence unit", props);
    }

    public boolean checkConnection(){

        try{
            entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I call the checkConnection method it tries to create a new entitymanager with the given parameters. If no connection can be established the entitymanagerfactory throws an exception and the method returns false.
When I test the method I can see the following results:

- All parameters are correct -> the method returns true as expected.
- The URL or the username are not correct -> the method returns false as expected.
- The drivername or the user password are not correct -> the method returns true but it should return false. <- This is my problem.


  Can someone tell me why it behaves like this and what is a proper way to test connection parameters without writing data to some database tables?

  At the moment I am using EclipseLink but I'm looking for some provider independent way.

  Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an EntityManager doesn't have to create any connection at that point. The JPA implementation could delay obtaining the connection until the first persist or flush for example (the JPA spec won't define when a connection has to be obtained).

Why not just use a simple few lines of JDBC to check your DB credentials? At least that way it works independent of how the JPA implementation has decided to handle connections (and those JPA properties have "jdbc" in the name since that is almost certainly what the JPA implementation is using itself to obtain connections).

Answer (score 0):

From [`JPA 2.0 Specification`](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) Section `8.2.1`

> The persistence-unit element consists of the name and transaction-type attributes and the following sub-elements: description, provider, jta-data-source, non-jta-data-source, mapping-file, jar-file, class, exclude-unlisted-classes, shared-cache-mode, validation-mode, and properties.
>
> The name attribute is **required**; the other attributes and elements are **optional**. Their semantics are described in the following subsections.

Entity Manager doesn't need a connection to be created as it **ONLY** needs the Persistence Unit name, I think you should go with `DataNucleus` suggesion to make a simple JDBC connection to validate your connection.